# Changing the admin User Profile page

Tags: users

I have a bunch of users that need to be managed by an admin. I have Advanced Custom Fields on the page but the User Profile page looks so ugly and doesn't render the fields the same way as it's a post. Is there a way I can have it so that it looks like a post?

Comment: Please share the URL of the user page and a url of a post with fields to see what's going on so we can help.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for the lack of clarity. It's the User Profile page when you are accessing the wp-admin page.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from designing your own profile page on the front-end... Simply create a new template file in your theme to handle the display and saving.

Answer (score 0):

You can style the user profile page with CSS by using [`admin_enqueue_scripts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts). Actually rearranging the ordering or structure of the content might require hooking into or overriding Advanced Custom Fields in some way, though.